# Java scanner not starting from beginning of file

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

First of all this is not a duplicate of other posts, because in my problem the scanner class does not recognize the beginning of the .txt file not the end, instead it starts approximately 1/2 way through the file.

Here is my code:

```
package Program;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String filename = "C:\\Users\\vroy\\Programming\\Text documents\\P&P.txt";

    File textFile = new File(filename);

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(textFile);

    // int value = reader.nextInt();
    // System.out.println(value);

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    reader.close();
}

}
```

Here is the .txt document that my program is reading:

http://www.goodreads.com/ebooks/download/1885.Pride_and_Prejudice?doc=2

My program starts printing out lines of text starting at: "with the ill-judged officiousness..."

It should start much further up the document.

Is this a problem with the scanner class?

Comment: Try to look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)

Comment: it perfectly works in my netbeans 8. for me what id do you use? try bufferreader to see if you get same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a problem with the scanner class?

Nope.

I just tested your code. The answer is pretty funny actually - I assume you are running this code in an IDE such as Eclipse. System.out.println() prints to the "Console". The console has a maximum number of lines it shows, and as your file is very long, it doesn't show the start.

It IS looping through all the lines. To prove this, make it increment a digit whenever it prints a line such as:

```
int counter = 0;
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    counter++;
}
```

You will see that counter is exactly the number of lines in the document.

Comment: but why it shows everything from beginning in netbeans ide?

Comment: Different IDEs or different settings will limit the console to different number of lines. There is no reason that any of his imported classes (java.io.File and java.util.Scanner) are not working unless he decomplied them, edited them, and recompiled (very unlikely)